# Magento admin template tag for secure link?

Tags: magento

I need to link to a secure page on the same website (https). I could probably hack something through xml, extend cms_page block, and put a secure instruction in constructor, but I'm just wondering if there's a template tag (for admin use) that would fetch me a secure link. I was trying to do this:

```
<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}secure_page">Secure page</a>
```

but magento eats the "secure_page" part, leaving only the config template tag in href part. Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="{{store url="secure_page" _secure="true"}}">Secure page</a>
```

Here is a list of applicable parameters: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

Comment: I knew about params, but didn't know you can use them in that context. Thanks